# Kotlin and Jackson: "Not enough information to infer parameter T in operator fun <T : > JsonNode!> set(p0: String!, p1: JsonNode!)"

Tags: android, kotlin, jackson

i'm updating from jackson library 2.9 to 2.11. But in some kotlin classes I get this errors:

> "Not enough information to infer parameter T in operator fun  set(p0: String!, p1: JsonNode!): T! Please specify it
>   explicitly."

This is a broken code example:

```
fun test() {
    var objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
    var testObjectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode()
    var result = objectMapper.createArrayNode()
    testObjectNode.set("test",testObjectNode)
}
```

In kotlin I have to cast the result of set action or specify the T type to make it work.

```
testObjectNode.set<JsonNode>("test",testObjectNode)
```

Could you explain me why on java I have to not explicity the type ?